# MySQL column1 increment by 1 if column2 changes

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to have a column that increments when column2 changes to sort it properly.

my example table that I want to happen:

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
|       1 | dog     |
|       1 | dog     |
|       2 | cat     |
|       2 | cat     |
|       3 | rat     |
+---------+---------+
```

if anyone can help, thank you.

Comment: Do you need auto-filled static column in the table structure, or you need such column in the query output?

Comment: Imagine that both rows (2,'cat') were deleted and than a row with column2='snake' is inserted - does column1 must be assigned to 2 or to 4?

Comment: @Akina I think no data will be deleted from the table.

In my current table, I only have the Column2, now I need to add the Column1 that increments when Column2 changes. 

my table has ORDER BY Column2 so it will always go like dog, dog, cat, cat etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DENSE_RANK` analytic function can handle this requirement without the need for the first column, e.g.

```sql
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Column2) Column1,
    Column2
FROM yourTable;
```

This answer assumes that you are running MySQL 8 or later.

Comment: I tried this and it works with my example table below, but the problem is when I use it to my actual table, the dense rank starts from random numbers like 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3.

maybe I just need to modify my code a bit for this to work, thank you for this answer.

SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.`column2`) AS `column1`,
    a.`column2`
FROM 
(
 SELECT 'dog' AS `column2`
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'dog' AS `column2`
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'cat' AS `column2`
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'cat' AS `column2`
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'rat' AS `column2`
) a 
ORDER BY a.`column2`;

Comment: @KimBarcelo Then you need a second column which maintains the ordering of each column.

Comment: yes, I already fixed it, thank you for the help :).